# Copying files in multiple directories in terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I am new to using the command line for operations, so forgive me if this question is obvious. I would like to move all files of a certain type (.aiff) from one directory that contains many sub-directories. The file structure looks like this:

```
directory
- subdir1
  -- sound.aiff 
  -- other.txt
- subdir2
  -- sound2.aiff
  -- other2.txt
```

I've tried using something like `cp -R /Users/me/directory/*.aiff /Users/me/newdirectory` but I get a "no such file or directory" error. I don't know how to specify that the files I want copied in the subdirectories must be .aiff files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cp -R /Users/me/directory/*/*.aiff /Users/me/newdirectory
```

But probably the destination `/Users/me/newdirectory` is missing.

You could verify this by doing:

```
file /Users/me/newdirectory
```

If the directory doesn't exist will print an error like:

```
Users/me/newdirectory: cannot open `/Users/me/newdirectory' (No such file or directory)
```

Create the directory with:

```
mkdir /Users/me/newdirectory
```

Next, try to copy the files again, if you want to move them use `mv` instead of `cp`

Another way is to use the command [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)), for example:

```
find /Users/me/directory -type f -iname "*.aiff" -exec mv {} /Users/me/newdirectory \;
```

In this example, the command `find` is going to search for in directory `/Users/me/directory/` only for files `-type f` that end (case insensitive) in `*.aiff` for each file found it will execute the command mv `exec mv {} /Users/me/newdirectory`. The `{}` is a placeholder.

Before moving you could test the command by just finding the desired types:

```
find . -iname "*.aiff"
```

This will search for files within the directory the command is executed, notice the `.` instead of a `/Users/me/directory/`